Strange behavior of symfony doctrine during phpunit test - field becomes null in database
I am using

Symfony v6.4.8
doctrine/orm 2.19.5
phpunit/phpunit 9.6.19

I have build an REST API GET endpoint /api/contract/{$id} in Symfony.
It performs an API request at another system, receiving that data and combining it with local database data and creates a new record in my database.
The problem I have is at / after the persist()/flush() in the Database, that sometimes the field $contract->eup is NULL in the database.
eup is defined as nvarchar(10) in a MSSQL database.
private function saveContract(EntityManager $em, array $data): ContractData
{        
    $contract = new ContractData();
    // [... some more variables]
    $contract->setEup($data['eup']);  // example: "2024-06-29"
    
    $em->persist($contract);
    $em->flush();

    return $contract;
}

Update: simplified code of the phpunit test:
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class ContractDataControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public static function contractProvider(): array
    {
        $testCases = array(
            ['18fac35b-4afe-476e-9094-1437deeb6f0a', 'stringValue1', '2024-06-29'],
        );
        return $testCases;
    }
    
    /**
     * @covers \App\Controller\API\ContractDataController::contract
     * @dataProvider contractProvider
     */
    public function testGetContractWhileLoggedIn($id, $expectValue1, $expectEup): void
    {
        $uri = $this->getUriWithSignature('/api/contract/', $id);

        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->disableReboot();
        $client->setServerParameter('HTTP_Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $_ENV['TOKEN']);
        $client->request('GET', $uri);

        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(200);

        $responseData = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);

        $this->assertSame($expectValue1, $responseData['value1']);
        // the other values are working, there are more values to test, code is simplyfied, only eup is empty at database.
        $this->assertSame($expectEup, $responseData['valueEup']); 
    }
}

When I call my API with Postman, the record is created correctly and the eup field in the database is filled with a string.
But when I run the phpunit test php bin/phpunit --filter myTest, it calls the api, the record is created in the database, but the eup field is NULL.

Other fields of this record are stored correctly at the test.

It is also possible to write the value of this field to other fields.

Also tried to a shorter string, but this is also not saved.

I have run the test with xdebug too and can confirm (together with my colleague) that $contract->eup is set and filled with a string at $em->persist($contract); but when we look after flush at the database SELECT * FROM ... the field eup is NULL.


Do you have an idea what could be wrong?
Update2:
I updated the logger config/packages/monolog.yaml
# add Doctrine-Handler
        doctrine:
            type: stream
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/doctrine.log'
            level: debug
            channels: ["doctrine"]

There I found out that the SQL INSERT INTO is not what i expect it to be:
Executing statement: INSERT INTO contract_data (contract_number) VALUES (?) (parameters: array{"1":"XYZ123456"}, types: array{"1":2})
The eup field is missing in the SQL command!
However I don't know what to change that the field is used there.

how does the code for the unit test look?

@duncan I added the ContractDataControllerTest above

(next time) the DDL of the table is also useful to have in the question. from your answer it is likely too late for that edit apart from completeness reasons. The DDL can help to better understand (or reproduce) the problem.

My solution for the problem with the SQL:
delete all files in ./var/cache/test/
After that the SQL command & the test were fine!
Attention:
Deleting the complete folder was not the best idea.
Now other tests failed because of missing cache files.
Could fix it with: php bin/console cache:warmup --env=test
